# ‘The’ for things that has already been mentioned

Tags: definite-article

The: used to indicate a person or thing that has already been mentioned

Only ‘a half apple’ has already been written. In this case, are ‘the’s used well in both sentences?

1. There’s a half apple. “The” apple weighs 150 grams.
2. There’s a half apple. “The” half apple weighs 75 grams.

That is, that just ‘a half apple’ has already been written means that both an apple and a half apple have been mentioned?

Comment: Your last paragraph is extremely confusing.

Comment: @gone fishin' again. Do I better erase the last paragraph?

Comment: Unless you can clarify what you mean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In both examples, it is more idiomatic to say "half an apple" rather than "a half apple".

In your first example, you might possibly mention the whole apple specifically, to avoid confusion.

> There is half an apple. The whole apple weighed 150grams.

It 'weighed' because the whole apple no longer exists.

For your second example, you could just use 'it' to refer directly back to the object last mentioned.

> There is half an apple. It weighs 75 grams.

Comment: I really really appreciate your answer. But I want to know about ‘a half apple’ also because I have occasion to use ‘a half mile.’

Comment: Half an apple, half a mile. Perhaps the US would be more likely to use 'a half mile' & I'd be more inclined to use that than 'a half apple'

Comment: I got what you mean, thank you.

Comment: @Jennifer There are grammatical differences in the way that quantities work for discrete objects (apples) and continuously variable quantities (miles), so it’s best not to extrapolate from one to the other.

Comment: @Mike Scott Thank you for advice, Professor Scott.

Comment: "But I want to know about ‘a half apple’ also because I have occasion to use ‘a half mile.’   Here is your problem.... You want to know about "half mile" but you ask a question about "half apple".   Don't ask about one thing and hope to get an answer about something else!

Comment: In some other stacks, you will be encouraged to create a "minimal working example" that (MWE) shows the problem.  But that doesn't work on [ell.se] because you have no way of knowing if your MWE actually works and actually is an example.  So please use the actual words in the problem that you have.   -- The use of "apples" is a "red flag".  People rarely want to talk about apples, but use them as simple countable nouns.  But what works for "apples" might not work in the real problem that you have.